# display dynamically images from local file instead of from url path in vuejs project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello Developers in this app I'm building in Vuejs , is happening something funny ... I'm trying to change path of images request according with some X result , then the image my vary attuning with the path modification.
My path was set in one of the app folder (assets) thus :

Path to images in folder assets:

```
..assets/
    dice1.png
    dice2.png
    dice3.png
    dice4.png
    dice5.png
    dice6.png
```

then in one of my computed methods is set a variable which eventually has as value the initial path string  ,

Computed

```js
functionX(){
   const assets = "../assets/dice"    =====variable asigned with value of part of the path====
   
   var x=document.getElementById(some)

   var y=1
    
   x.style.backgroundImage="url(" + assets + y + ".png)"
}
```

then it throws me an error 404, as if the request was to an external URL.
[image]
The situation is different if in fact i use a external URL to fetch that images, then it works perfectly .But as soon as i change that to a local file throws me this error.
How could i solve this problem of not letting me work with local file sttled images dynamically?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the path to the local file very well.

`../path/to/image` indicates one folder up

`./path/to/image` indicates current folder

So check the path of the image relative to the path of the file you are calling the image. If it they are in the same folder `./` or in another folder up one directory `../`

Comment: the path to the images is fine ....cause the images shows up ...the problem is when i try to change it dynamically